# How to deal with a function like $f(x)=\inf \{\alpha >0 : \alpha^{-1}x\in I\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

---

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval that contains $0$ and $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as:

$$f(x)=\inf \{\alpha >0 : \alpha^{-1}x\in I\}$$

Show that:

- $f(cx)=cf(x)$ for all $c>0$;
- $I =\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x)<1\}$;
- There exists $K>0$ such that $0\leq f(x)\leq K|x|$.

---

But I am really confused even to parse that function mentally. Can you help?

Comment: Try to compute $f(x)$ for a concrete case first, e.g. $I=(-1, 2)$. Distinguish the cases $x < 0$, $x=0$, and $x> 0$.

Comment: @MartinR If I take $f(1)$, then I'd have $\alpha^{-1}=i \in I$, so $\alpha^{-1}=\text{element in } I$, so $\alpha$ is the inverse of those elements which are bigger than $0$. And $f(1)$ is the infimum of that set. Does that make sense?

Comment: For $x > 0$ and the above interval you have $\alpha^{-1}x \in I$ iff $\alpha^{-1}x < 2$ iff $ \alpha > x/2$. Therefore $f(x) = x/2$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: @MartinR This was really helpful. I'll try to answer it now.

Comment: @MartinR I am a bit confused: What happens when $x=0$? We would have $\alpha^{-1} \cdot 0 = i \in I$, but then $\alpha^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0$ which means that $f(0)=-1$? Is that correct? The set of all $\alpha^{-1}$ such that $\alpha^{-1}x\in I$ would be $(-1,2)\setminus \{0\}$, I guess.

Comment: If $x = 0$ then $\alpha^{-1}x  \in I$ for *all* $\alpha > 0$ (note that $0 \in I$ is given). So the infimum is zero, i.e. $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

With respect to the last part:

> There exists $K>0$ such that $0\leq f(x)\leq K|x|$.

$f(x) \ge0$ should be obvious. Also $f(0) = 0$ so that it suffices to consider the case $x \ne 0$.

Choose $K > 0$ such that $1/K \in I$ and $-1/K \in I$. Then
$$
\left| \left(K |x| \right)^{-1} x\right| = \frac 1 K \implies \left(K |x| \right)^{-1} x \in I \implies f(x) \le K |x| \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $I$ is an open interval containing $0$ so it is of the form $I=(a,b)$ with $a<0$ and $b>0$

- $f(cx)=\inf \{\alpha >0 : \alpha^{-1}cx\in I\}=c\inf \{\alpha >0 : \alpha^{-1}x\in I\}=cf(x)$
- Let us prove this in two parts:

If $x\in I$ then $f(x)\leq1$ (since, if $\alpha=1$ we have $\alpha^{-1}x=x\in I$). Notice that $I$ is an open interval, so there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset I$, and so there is some $\beta<1$ (choosen such that $1-\beta$ is as small as needed) satisfying $\beta^{-1}x\in(x-\epsilon,x)\subset I$. This proves that $f(x)<1$, and so $I \subset\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x)<1\}$.

Now, by contradiction, let us assume that there is some $y\in \{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x)<1\} \setminus I$. Since $f(y)<1$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall~\alpha\in(f(y),f(y)+\epsilon)\subset(0,1)$ we have $\alpha^{-1}y\in I$. Since $y\notin I$ we have two cases: $y<a$ or $y>b$. This gives us a contradiction, because in the first case   $\alpha^{-1}y<y<a$, and so $\alpha^{-1}y\notin I$ and in the second case $\alpha^{-1}y>y>b$ and so $\alpha^{-1}y\notin I$.

- The fact that $f(x)\geq 0$ is obvious. Let $K=\max\lbrace\frac{1}{a},\frac{-1}{b}\rbrace$. If $x\in I$ and $x>0$ then $\alpha^{-1}x\in I$ iff $\alpha^{-1}x< a$ iff $\alpha>\frac{x}{a}$, so $f(x)=\frac{x}{a}$. If $x\in I$ and $x<0$ then $\alpha^{-1}x\in I$ iff $\alpha^{-1}x> b$ iff $\alpha>\frac{x}{b}$, so $f(x)=\frac{x}{b}$. Also, we have trivially $f(0)=0$. So we have found what $f$ is and it trivially satisfies $f(x)<K|x|$.

Notice that we could have found the expression for $f$ at the beginning and then solve the exercise, but since it is not needed in the two first parts, I thought it is more interesting this solution.